# how to make database driver support build with graalvm like quarkus jdbc extenstion

Tags: quarkus, graalvm

I have looked at the source code of quarkus jdbc mysql and found that there is no reflect config or build at runtime config，how to make database driver support build with graalvm，have any sample or jdbc extension doc ? Thx.

Comment: or else just import database jdbc driver，how to successfully build native image with graalvm

Answer (score 0):

You need to make extension for quarkus like in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/extensions/jdbc just copy any of them and create your JDBC extension from it and you have your JDBC driver ready for quarkus and graalvm.

For example MySQL reflection configs made in java like below

```java
public final class MySQLJDBCReflections {

    @BuildStep
    void registerDriverForReflection(BuildProducer<ReflectiveClassBuildItem> reflectiveClass) {

        reflectiveClass.produce(ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(Driver.class.getName()).build());
        reflectiveClass.produce(
                ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(FailoverDnsSrvConnectionUrl.class.getName())
                        .build());
        reflectiveClass.produce(
                ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(FailoverConnectionUrl.class.getName()).build());
        reflectiveClass
                .produce(ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(SingleConnectionUrl.class.getName())
                        .build());
        reflectiveClass.produce(
                ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(LoadBalanceConnectionUrl.class.getName())
                        .build());
        reflectiveClass.produce(ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(LoadBalanceDnsSrvConnectionUrl.class.getName())
                .build());
        reflectiveClass.produce(ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(ReplicationDnsSrvConnectionUrl.class.getName())
                .build());
```

Check [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/jdbc/mysql/deployment/MySQLJDBCReflections.java) for full source code.

And you can find MySQL runtime configuration [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/jdbc/mysql/runtime/MySQLServiceBindingConverter.java).

Reference: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1748